# Cannot set property of undefined in directive

Tags: angularjs

My objective is to filter ngModel value with number decimal 2 pipe which is not possible from cshtml

I used below blog example to create custom directive:
https://blog.krusen.dk/angularjs-decimals-browsers/

I am getting error:

> [SFC Error] Cannot set property '$render' of undefined

I dont want to put a check of NgModel undefined as it is always supposed to be there however why i am getting ngModel undefined in directive

```
app.directive("decimals", function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: "A", // Only usable as an attribute of another HTML element
        require: "?ngModel",
        scope: {
            decimals: "@",
            decimalPoint: "@"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            var decimalCount = parseInt(scope.decimals) || 2;
            var decimalPoint = scope.decimalPoint || ".";

            // Run when the model is first rendered and when the model is changed from code
            ngModel.$render = function() {
                if (ngModel.$modelValue != null && ngModel.$modelValue >= 0) {
                    if (typeof decimalCount === "number") {
                        element.val(ngModel.$modelValue.toFixed(decimalCount).toString().replace(".", ","));
                    } else {
                        element.val(ngModel.$modelValue.toString().replace(".", ","));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: If `ngModel` is always supposed to defined why did you make it optional with `require: "?ngModel"`?

Comment: I have removed ? still error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have go the answer from
[Get value from ngModel in custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060733/get-value-from-ngmodel-in-custom-directive)

I changed sequence of NGModel Parameter